# Why does Kubernetes Performance decreases with Resource Request for memory?

Tags: apache, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, lamp

I have a LAMP stack setup on GKE where I have been using custom docker image and starting my Apache with httpd -DFOREGROUND in entrypoint.sh ( taken from official httpd docker image) .Currently, the default preforks setting for apache being used.

The issue is when I am setting a resource request for memory the application is becoming too sluggish and slow but when I remove the resource request and just everything works fine. From my understanding resource Request is just for scheduling of pod , I don't understand how it plays a role in performance.

From the observations, The pod's mem utilization never crosses the request I placed.

Below are the data:

Whenever a pod starts it creates 10 process

```
root           1  0.0  0.3 511496 30724 ?        Ss   17:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache         90  0.1  0.5 620584 48736 ?        S    19:09   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache        100  0.1  0.4 526332 37044 ?        S    19:34   0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root         103  0.1  0.0  54060  4336 pts/0    Ss+  19:35   0:03 watch ps aux
apache        446  0.0  0.4 528404 38496 ?        S    19:41   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache        493  0.0  0.4 528048 37692 ?        S    19:42   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache       1038  0.0  0.4 528104 37616 ?        S    19:51   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache       1039  0.1  0.4 528232 38328 ?        S    19:51   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache       1776  0.0  0.4 528104 38776 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache       1779  0.0  0.4 528104 38040 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache       1780  0.0  0.4 526056 35372 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache       1781  0.0  0.4 528104 37592 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

At the time when I look at my pod memory usage:

```
NAME                        CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
web-6f58cf5b67-lfc46   17m          231Mi
```

So if we sum the memory usage ~40m for each process, it is double the memory which is showing by pods.

Can someone please explain this behaviour.

Comment: Resource request is only used by a scheduler, it may not affect performance in any way.

Comment: I totally agree. Can u see any pattern in here which might be going wrong? That's what I am wondering what might be the reason, maybe adding resources triggering something else? The moment I remove the request ,everything goes back to normal. The page which take 2m takes 2s without the request allocation

Comment: Use the standard profiling tools that your platform provides to you to investigate it.

Comment: Could you please share your desployment spec, or something that could be reproducible? Because is hard to say anything from kubernetes side if you don'tshare any details about your cluster and the deployment.